# set canvas size to the same size of a bitmap image

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

I have made a custom ImageView which has an onDraw method that draws a circle on particular pixels. The problem is I am using the ImageView to load a bitmap image and I need the canvas to be the same size as the bitmap image and the ImageView holder to be the same size again..

does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
Canvas c = new Canvas();
c = holder.lockCanvas();
c.save();
c.drawBitmap(yourBitmap,0,0,null);
c.restore();
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

It is my understanding that you don't need to worry about the canvas size.

Comment: My custom view class (that has the onDraw method) currently extends ImageView. Do I need to extend SurfaceHolder instead? Also how do I implement scrolling and zooming on this?

Comment: I usually use SurfaceViews instead of ImageViews for this type of thing. I'm not sure about any performance comparisons though.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't determining the Bitmap size in your onMeasure() and setting the custom view size accordingly work?